# insert data into database through MVC model using Dao and Bean class

Tags: java, database, servlets, model-view-controller

Please help finding me error. Though no compilation error but data is not being processed into database.
There are just no syntax error in these codes. Even I've checked through multiple sites but nothing different I can spot.

mvc package.

RegisterDao.java

```
package mvc;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RegisterDao {

    public static Connection getCon() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                }
                catch(Exception e){};
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hcs","root","1234");
    return con;
    }
    public int addRecordpatient(User a)
    {
        int i=0;
        Connection con;
        try {
            con = getCon();
        String qr="insert into signin(phone, name, password, gender, bgrp, age) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qr);
        ps.setInt(1, a.getPhone());
        ps.setString(2, a.getName());
        ps.setString(3, a.getPassword());
                ps.setString(4, a.getGender());
                ps.setString(5, a.getBgrp());
                ps.setInt(6, a.getAge());
        int j=ps.executeUpdate();

                if (j!=0)  //Just to ensure data has been inserted into the database
                {System.out.println("success"); }


        con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        //return i;
    return 0;
        }

}
```

User.java

```
package mvc;

public class User {
private int phone;
private String name;
private String password;
private String gender;
private String bgrp;
private int age;
public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getBgrp() {
    return bgrp;
}
public void setBgrp(String bgrp) {
    this.bgrp = bgrp;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

servlet -->
psignup.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import mvc.RegisterDao;
import mvc.User;
@WebServlet("/psignup")
public class psignup extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public psignup() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        int phone=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phone"));
                String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
                String bgrp=request.getParameter("bgrp");
                int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
        User b=new User();
                b.setPhone(phone);
        b.setName(name);
        b.setPassword(password);
                b.setGender(gender);
                b.setBgrp(bgrp);
                b.setAge(age);
        try{
    RegisterDao rd= new RegisterDao();
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

                }
                catch(Exception e){out.print(e);}
    }
}
```

signup jsp page --->
index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="psignup" class=" form-group">
                    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</h1>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="no">Contact</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="no" name="phone" placeholder="eg. 9876543210"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="n">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n" name="name" placeholder="eg. abc pqr xyz"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="p">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="p" name="password" placeholder="eg. Abc123!"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="n">Gender</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="g" name="gender" placeholder="eg. male"/>
                    </div>                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add">blood group</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bgrp" name="bgrp" placeholder="eg. O+"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="no">Age</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="eg. 101"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn-block btn-primary" id="submit"/>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

database (working properly). signin --->

```
Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| phone    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bgrp     | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: I think you posted servlet twice.  DAO is not present.  I'd recommend setting a breakpoint in the servlet and seeing that the data you enter in the JSP actually arrives on the server side.  Once you know that, trace it into the DAO and see where the database went wrong.  You are taking a risk: no validation or scrubbing of HTTP request data.  That's asking for injection issues.

Comment: You seem to create the `User` object but where is your code regarding the database interaction? You instantiate a `RegisterDao` but you do not see to use it. Also your class name and general code syntax is way off.

Comment: You have a try-catch for loading the database driver; the catch does nothing. Are you sure the driver gets loaded?

Comment: connect-debugger:
`Attached JPDA debugger to localhost:9009
In-place deployment at /home/shashank/Desktop/hcs/build/web
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, Connection refused (Connection refused), false
/home/shashank/Desktop/hcs/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1152: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)`    On debugging this appeared. I corrected my twice pasted error. @Aris

Comment: yeah. There's no problem leaving  catch empty. @WilliamBurnham

Comment: I resolved my database connection error. But even now code isn't processing what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a try-catch for loading the database driver; the catch does nothing. Are you sure the driver gets loaded?

Your `RegisterDao` DAO (data access object) has an `addRecordpatient` method that takes your `User` DTO (data transfer object) and puts it in the database by converting it to an actual query with your prepared statement.

Your servlet doesn't call this method, it just instantiates the DAO. You need to add

```
rd.addRecordpatient(user);
```

after you've instantiated the object.

Have you tried debugging this? Also no data validation is done anywhere. You should add validation logic to your posted data before sending it to the database.

Comment: Yeah. I did this. But code still didn't  worked for me. And no failure occur on debugging. @William